# AWS Cloudformation ELB healthcheck (verify_instance_health) does not work with Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, amazon-elb, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to get AWS cloudformation to work with AutoScalingRollingUpdate on Ubuntu AMI. I am following the template from AWS named `ELBGuidedAutoScalingRollingUpgrade.json`.

Generally, Autoscaling group is waiting on the signal from EC2 instance behind ELB, when ELB marks it as InService, Autoscaling group will continue to do the following job.

I can get cfn-hup up and running on **ubuntu**, however `cfn-init.log` got error for configSets, the messages from cfn-init.log are below:

[cfn-init.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Wzk.png)
The verify_instance_health codes from AWS example are below: 
[verify_instance_health codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQEoT.png)

The cfn-hup.log got the error message:

> Error: Could not find configuration at /etc/cfn

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have listener running on the port that will be checked. Also ensure that the port is allowed on instance's security group and firewall. If health checker is configured to check via http, make sure that instance's http listener responds with http response code 200.